How to redirect the Home page if session has null using Pipeline
We've set up the website using session data, and each page relies on this data.
Should the session data be missing, I must redirect the user back to the main page. This scenario arises when a user attempts to directly access a particular page through the browser without a session. In such cases, we must redirect the user to the main page. How can we accomplish this functionality within Sitecore using a pipeline or a common method?
We have stored the session value like this
Session.SetObjectAsJson("_MySessionObject", userSessionData);

get the session data using below code
Session.GetObjectFromJson<BaseSessionData>("_MySessionObject");

Thanks in advance,

You can create a processor inside mvc.requestBegin pipeline to check that the value of session key exist and if not then return to the home(main) page. Inside this pipeline,  HttpContext.Current.Session is not null and context item is also available, hence can be used to read session key and make decison whether to redirect.

Create a custom processor as below, that reads the value of the session key and redirects to home page if it is not set.

using Sitecore.Data.Items;
using Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin;
using Sitecore.Links;
using Sitecore.Web;

public class RedirectToHomePage : RequestBeginProcessor
{
    // Pipline to check session object is set
    public override void Process(RequestBeginArgs args)
    {
       Item homeItem = GetHomeItem();
       if (Sitecore.Context.Item != null && homeItem != null && Sitecore.Context.Item.ID != homeItem.ID)
       {
          var session = args.RequestContext.HttpContext.Session;
          if (session != null && session["UserLogedIn"] != null)
          {
             bool userLoggedIn = (bool)session["UserLogedIn"];
             if (!userLoggedIn)
             {
                Redirect(homeItem);
             }
          }
          else
          {
             Redirect(homeItem);
          }
       }
    }
    // Fetch the Home(Main) Item where the redirect should happen
    public Item GetHomeItem()
    {
       if (Sitecore.Context.Database != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath))
       {
         Item homeItem = Sitecore.Context.Database.GetItem(Sitecore.Context.Site.StartPath);
         return homeItem;
       }
       return null;
    }
    // Redirect to Home Item
    public void Redirect(Item homeItem)
    {
       string homePageUrl = LinkManager.GetItemUrl(homeItem);
       WebUtil.Redirect(homePageUrl);
    }
}


Patch the above processor as below inside the mvc.requestBegin pipeline. You can run the above processor only on Content Delivery server through enabling role based check.

<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:role="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/role/">
    <sitecore role:require="ContentDelivery">
      <pipelines>
          <mvc.requestBegin>
                <processor patch:before="*[@type='Sitecore.Mvc.Pipelines.Request.RequestBegin.SetupPageContext, Sitecore.Mvc']" type="SitecoreCustomExtensions.Pipelines.RedirectToHomePage, SitecoreCustomExtensions" />
            </mvc.requestBegin>
        </pipelines>
    </sitecore>
</configuration>

Using above way, you can make sure user gets redirected to home page whenever the session key is not set.
Note: You can also use following helper method to set session values inside Sitecore.
Sitecore.Web.WebUtil.SetSessionValue("UserLogedIn", true);

Let me know in case you have any doubts. Hope this helps!!!

That's work, Thanks CKhanna

Glad to hear that @Rameshkumar!!!

You can create a custom pipeline processor that checks for the session data and redirects if the session is null.Below are the steps given to implement this:

Create a Custom Pipeline Processor
Register the Custom Processor in the Pipeline

Step 1: Create a custom pipeline processor. This processor will check the session and perform the redirect if the session is null.
using Sitecore.Pipelines.HttpRequest;
using System.Web;
using Sitecore.Diagnostics;
using System.Web.SessionState;
namespace YourNamespace.Pipelines
{
   public class CheckSessionProcessor : HttpRequestProcessor
   {
       public override void Process(HttpRequestArgs args)
       {
           if (HttpContext.Current == null)
               return;
           var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;
           // Check if session exists
           if (session != null)
           {
               var sessionData = session.GetObjectFromJson<BaseSessionData>("_MySessionObject");
               if (sessionData == null)
               {
                   // Redirect to the home page
                   HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/", true);
               }
           }
       }
   }
}

Step 2: Register the Custom Processor in the Pipeline
Next, register the custom processor in the App_Config configuration files. Locate the httpRequestBegin pipeline and add your custom processor.
Open the App_Config file and add the following configuration:
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/">
<sitecore>
<pipelines>
<httpRequestBegin>
<processor type="YourNamespace.Pipelines.CheckSessionProcessor, YourAssemblyName" />
</httpRequestBegin>
</pipelines>
</sitecore>
</configuration>

Step 3: Session Helper Methods
Ensure you have helper methods for setting and getting the session object as JSON. These methods can be placed in a utility class.
public static class SessionExtensions
{
   public static void SetObjectAsJson(this HttpSessionState session, string key, object value)
   {
       session[key] = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(value);
   }
   public static T GetObjectFromJson<T>(this HttpSessionState session, string key)
   {
       var value = session[key]?.ToString();
       return value == null ? default(T) : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(value);
   }
}


CheckSessionProcessor Class: This custom processor checks the session object for the presence of the session data. If the session data is missing, it redirects the user to the home page.
Pipeline Configuration: The processor is added to the httpRequestBegin pipeline, which ensures it runs on every request.
Session Extensions: These helper methods allow storing and retrieving objects in the session as JSON.


here i'm getting null, here var session = HttpContext.Current.Session;

Ensure that the session state module is enabled in your web.config. This is usually enabled by default, but it's good to double-check
Move your session check to a later pipeline stage where the session is guaranteed to be available, such as the preprocessRequest pipeline.
